# Web Api 2 - Roteamentos não estão funcionando

Tags: asp.net, web-service, rest, asp.net-web-api

Criei um web service REST usando Web Api 2, e em desenvolvimento tudo é funcional. Estou usando uma pequena variação da rota padrão:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{numProtocolo}",
    defaults: new { numProtocolo = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

No entanto, quando é criado o aplicativo em produção no IIS (versão 7, Windows 2008 Server 32 bits) e executado em produção, retorna 404 para rotas que são válidas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema acontece porque o IIS não está conseguindo entender qual mecanismo de reescrita de URL deve usar. Para resolvê-lo, devemos adicionar a seguinte linha na nossa cadeia do `web.config`, em `<system.webServer>`:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
```

O código completo ficará assim (suprimindo outros nós eventualmente existentes em `<system.webserver>`:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
</system.webServer>
```

Agora, as rotas funcionam como deveriam porque o IIS foi instruído a utilizar os módulos gerenciados pelo projeto para todas as requests, ao invés de tentar determinar qual módulo deve aplicar.

Comment: Vale a pena levar em consideração que, quando o parâmetro `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests` estiver ligado, TODAS as requisições são passadas pelo pipeline de TODOS os módulos - arquivos estáticos inclusive (.js, .html, etc.) Em certas situações isso pode acarretar uma substancial perda de performance no site como um todo.

Answer (score 0):

No seu caso o IIS não está conseguindo resolver as rotas. Caso esteja utilizando `inheritance chain` para implementar seus *endpoints*, utilize a seguinte solução:

```
    public class CustomDirectRouteProvider : DefaultDirectRouteProvider
    {
        protected override IReadOnlyList<IDirectRouteFactory> GetActionRouteFactories(
            HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
        {
            return actionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<IDirectRouteFactory>(true);
        }
    }
```

E, na sua seção de inicialização do HttpConfiguration:

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(new CustomDirectRouteProvider());
```