# Asp.net MVC4 no IIS 6 - Página não encontrada

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

Estou com problemas ao publicar uma aplicação ASP.NET MVC4 em um IIS 6.
As configurações parecem estar corretas, porém o browser mostra "erro 404".

Alguém já passou por isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vá em application configuration, no seu diretório virtual e insira um "wildcard" (Application COnfiguration > Mappings > Wildcard application) apontando para a seguinte DLL (verifique a versão do seu .net (4 ou 2)

```
c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll
```

Lembre-se de desmarcar a opção "verify file exists".

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: você tem a opção de responder sua própria pergunta já na criação da mesma... Acostume-se a criar assim quando tiver esse aspecto mais de "wiki"! Em todo caso, obrigado por compartilhar.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica!

Answer (score 1):

[Acabei de postar uma pergunta/resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/7474/web-api-2-roteamentos-nao-estao-funcionando) nesse sentido, veja se resolve para você!

Basicamente, é um problema com UrlRewrite. Adicione isso ao seu web.config em `<system.webServer>`:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
</system.webServer>
```